How can I make this flat object match the curved object without deforming to the point of losing its edge measurements?
I've been trying for weeks to make the flat object curved similarly to the curved object. I've tried shrink-wrap, I've tried curve modifier, have even tried cloth physics (which was closest and was fun but the edges would end up jagged and rough).
The main problem I have is the edges will elongate and deform. I realize you can't really deform an object without deforming its edges, but I want to keep edges relatively the same while getting the matching curvature/shape.


Have you tried applying a lattice to the desired object to be curved and applying the lattice with a shrink wrap modifier to the curved object? https://youtu.be/7hq92JvHq2g?si=aXrNyfiVUxsxGEQS

That is what I did earlier today I had found that same video and followed it to a T, what happens is the sides get compressed and shortened and however I move things around or scale it doesn't fix it

Maybe check the Wrap Tools addon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hVl8unmNxE https://blendermarket.com/products/wrapping-tools
